# Jupyter Notebook Start-up folder to be current folder (Mac)

Tags: macos, jupyter-notebook, startup-folder

How do I change Jupyter Notebook's start-up folder to be the directory that I started it in terminal? I have tried `jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=%CD%` but it gave me an error:

```
[C 00:31:27.239 NotebookApp] Bad config encountered during initialization:
[C 00:31:27.239 NotebookApp] No such notebook dir: ''/Users/username/%CD%''
```

Is there a better way to change start-up folder on Jupyter Notebook? Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I `cd` into a directory then both `jupyter notebook` and `jupyter lab` start in the current folder.

I am running Ventura (13.1).

Comment: Yeah I assume it was this way when Jupyter Notebook was initially installed on this machine. Someone changed the configuration and it will always start from a specific directory, which is annoying. I just figured out how to change it back. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the configuration of Jupiter Notebook and it worked. Here are the steps:

1. find the configuration dir at `jupyter --config-dir`
2. In the configuration dir, edit jupyter_notebook_config.py and change to or add this line `c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = ''`

Now it will start from where the starting directory is.